# How to save output predictions into a CSV in weka using command-line by loading a saved model?

Tags: java, csv, command-line, weka, prediction

I am running a weka command to predict by loading an already trained and saved model. I need these predictions of the test file on the loaded model to be saved as a CSV file. What command should I use in commandline to do the same.

I have already tried the following:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar -Xmx28G weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier \
-classifications "weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.CSV -p 1-3,20,29"  \
-T test.arff  -l ./j48.model  > only_predictions.csv
```

I have tried the above command with all the permutations of placing the -classifications "weka..." at different places in the same command itself as was suggested in some answer to similar question. It gives me illegal option "-classifications" error each time.

```
-classifications "weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.CSV -p first" \
-l $model \
-T $dataset \
|tail -n+6 |head -n -1
```

This also didn't work for me as was suggested in one of the similar question.

Also tried training and predicting in a single command but didn't work

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar -Xmx28G weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -classifications \
"weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.CSV -p 1-3,20,29 -distribution -file predictions.csv" \
-t ${g1_train_arff} -T test.arff  -F "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove -R 1,26,28" \
-W weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -c last -- -C 0.25 -M 5
```

Also, using **java -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar weka.core.Version** command gives me **3.6.10**.

I expected a proper csv file created with the output prediction values along with the attribute range given with the -p option.
Please help me with the problem. Thanks in advance.